# Number of background processes

Tags: shell

I'd like to put something in my $PROMPT that displays the number of background processes. Is there a variable or way to identify a process as backgrounded that I can script for?

Comment: What operating system? What shell?

Answer (score 1):

The command **jobs** gives a list of background processes. You can do:

```
jobs | wc -l
```

to count the number of background jobs.

Comment: This doesn't display it in the prompt though

Answer (score 1):

If you're in linux, and using the *bash* shell, you can use the `$( )` as part of the `$PS` variable to run a command. The command `ps -ea -ocmd,stat | grep -w S | wc -l` should give you a list of all the processes that are not currently sleeping (I assume that's what you mean by "background"). So say the normal prompt is:

```
PS1='\[\033[01;31m\]\h\[\033[01;34m\] \W \$\[\033[00m\] '
```

Then you can insert the background procs by:

```
PS1='\[\033[01;31m\]\h\[\033[01;34m\] \W $( ps -ea -ocmd,stat | grep -w S | wc -l ) \$\[\033[00m\] '
```

which results with a prompt like: `myhost ~ 61 #`

If you want the actual background **jobs** that are part of the current shell, then replace the command with `jobs | wc -l`:

```
PS1='\[\033[01;31m\]\h\[\033[01;34m\] \W $( jobs | wc -l ) \$\[\033[00m\] '
```